# how to make div element go under nav bar when scrolling up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the div elements below the nav bar go under nav bar when i scroll up. Currently, the contents go over the nav bar when i scroll up. I tried using some of the solutions in stackoverflow but somehow it does not work for my case. Would kindly appreciate your help.

This is the HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class = "container-fluid">
  <div class = "navigation-bar" id = "nav-bar">
    <div class = "w3-top">
    <div class = "w3-bar w3-border w3-card-4" >
      <a href = "#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">About</a>
      <a href = "#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Portfolio</a>
      <a href = "#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Contact</a>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <body>
  <div class = "Intro" id = "myIntro">
   <div class="w3-panel w3-card-4">
    <h4 class = "header" align = "center"> My workspace</h4>
    <p>
     <table style="width:90%">
       <tr>
         <td align = "center"><i>Aspiring developer</i></td>
         <td align = "center"><i>Tech enthusiast</i>
         <td align = "center"><i>Loves fishing</i>
       </tr>
       </table>
      </p>
   <hr>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is the current css code:

```
.navigation-bar{
  z-index: 1;
}
body {
  padding: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
h4 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

You can see what happens through here: https://codepen.io/chawin/pen/EWBaxo

Comment: is your problem solved? If yes, maybe you can "accept" one of the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in your code, the `div` element goes under the nav bar. It appears to be "go over" because the nav bar's background color is transparent (`rgba(0,0,0,0)`). To fix the issue, all you need is define the nav bar's background color as white:

```
.navigation-bar .w3-top {
  background: white;
}
```

Please check the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shaochuancs/pen/xqoppJ).

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use the `z-index` attribute.

The default is 0, so if the other elements have not been changed, you can just set the `z-index` of the nav-bar to `1` and it will display above all other elements.

** NOTE: For z-index to work, you must use positioning.

i.e: `position: fixed`

You need to rewrite your page, properly. After playing around, you can see the bar starting to display over the text http://prntscr.com/ettdzp, but you've done things like add padding which has offset, as well as use external style sheets. Placing `divs` outside the body in free-space is not a good idea, also.

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal navigation bar

```
.navigation-bar{ 
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
 } 
body { 
     margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of z-index and position fixed. Also make sure no other element has a z-index higher than your nav bar.

```
#nav-bar{ 
     position: fixed;
     z-index:99;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
.w3-top{
  z-index: 10;
  background: white;
  left: 0;
}
```